# using custom data types in haskell

Tags: haskell

I made these custom data types:

```
data BakedGoods = Muffin
                | Croissant
                | Cookie
                deriving (Eq, Show)

data Muffin = Blueberry
            | SaltedCaramel
            | Cheesecake
```

then I tried to use them in a function that returns the price of the BakedGoods:

```
price :: BakedGoods -> Int
price a 
  | a == Blueberry = 2

[...]
```

and I keep getting this error:

```
 Couldn't match expected type ‘BakedGoods’ with actual type ‘Muffin’
```

I get the point but unfortunately I have no idea how to fix it, do you have any ideas? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```hs
data BakedGoods = Muffin -- ...
data Muffin = Blueberry -- ...
```

You are **not** saying that `BakedGoods`'s data constructors should include all of `Muffin`'s. You are **actually** saying that you should create a new `Muffin` data constructor, completely unrelated to the `Muffin` type, and that `Muffin` data constructor is a `BakedGood`. If you want to merge the two, then declare them merged:

```hs
data BakedGoods = Blueberry
                | SaltedCaramel
                | Cheesecake
                | Croissant
                | Cookie
```

Then `Blueberry` would be a `BakedGoods`. But, if you want to retain the fact that they are muffins, then you can make a `MuffinFlavor` type and have your `Muffin` contain a `MuffinFlavor`:

```hs
data BakedGoods = Muffin MuffinFlavor
                | Croissant
                | Cookie

data MuffinFlavor = Blueberry | SaltedCaramel | Cheesecake
```

And now you can create muffins with `Muffin Blueberry`.

Answer (score 7):

This is a bit confusing for beginners.

An algebraic datatype is of the form: `data` *typename* `=` *constructor1* `|` *constructor2* etc.

A type can have the same name as a constructor, *even of a different type.* So your code has two *different* `Muffin`s - a *type* called `Muffin` (with constructors `Blueberry`, `SaltedCaramel`  and `Cheescake`), and a *constructor* `Muffin` for the type `BakedGoods`. As far as the compiler is concerned, they are completely unconnected.

The code you want looks like this:

```
data BakedGoods = Muffin Muffin
    | ...
```

This means: The *type* `BakedGoods` has a *constructor* called `Muffin`, which contains one *field* of *type* `Muffin`.

You would then pattern-match it like so:

```
price :: BakedGoods -> Int
price (Muffin Blueberry) = 2
...
```

Which means: when the argument (which must be a `BakedGoods`) has a top-level constructor matching `Muffin`, whose field (of type `Muffin`) matches `Blueberry`, then return 2.

Happy Haskelling!

Answer (score 3):

If you write

```
data BakedGoods = Muffin | …
```

then this is not a union of the data constructors of the `Muffin` type with other data constructors. You here simply say that `BakedGood`s has a data constructor named `Muffin`, the fact that there is a type named `Muffin` does not matter.

You can wrap a `Muffin` object in the `Muffin` data constructor, like:

```
data BakedGoods
  = Muffin Muffin  -- ← parameter for the Muffin data type
  | Croissant
  | Cookie
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Then you thus can perform pattern matching on the value wrapped in the `Muffin` data constructor:

```
price :: BakedGoods -> Int
price (Muffin Blueberry) = 2
```